# Where does gradle install Gcloud?

Tags: windows, gradle, gcloud

I used the Gradle Cloud plugin to deploy my app. It seems it has installed a second installation of gcloud because the path variables of the command line were not up to date. Now after a command line restart, it says that there is a second installation of gcloud on the path, which is the one that I wanted Gradle to use originally. I want to keep the second installation, where is the installation that gradle made so that I may clean it up?

Gradle Gcloud: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/java/gradle-reference

Message from the Gradle gcloud installation (the gcloud installation listed here I want to keep) (userhome redacted):

```
Please remove the following to avoid confusion or accidental invocation:

<userhome>\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\gsutil.cmd
<userhome>\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\gcloud-crc32c.exe
<userhome>\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\endpointscfg.py
<userhome>\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\java_dev_appserver.sh
<userhome>\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\bq.cmd
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it with more log output from gradle. The path is:

```
<userhome>\AppData\Local\google\ct4j-cloud-sdk\LATEST\google-cloud-sdk\bin\gcloud.cmd
```

However gradle doesn't give a shit about an already present installation. It just reinstalls the gcloud cli separate. Unsure how to solve.